# How To Make It Responsive for Desktop and Mobile?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have made this design using CSS and Bootstrap. I am Also Using Bootstrap. The Problem occurring is that this is not responsive. Can Anyone help me to make this responsive?

HTML:

```css
.ordering .spanone {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  left: 43%;
  right: 50%;
  font-size: 25px;
  top: 12%;
}

.ordering .spananother {
  position: absolute;
  width: 138px;
  left: 35%;
  right: 50%;
  font-size: 16px;
  top: 35%;
}

.ordering .spanthird {
  position: absolute;
  width: 138px;
  top: 45%;
  left: 39%;
  right: 50%;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.ordering .spanfourth {
  position: absolute;
  width: 138px;
  top: 55%;
  left: 35%;
  right: 50%;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.ordering .spanfifth {
  position: absolute;
  width: 229px;
  top: 66%;
  left: 24%;
  right: 50%;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.orange {
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #4C4245;
  height: 226px !important;
  width: 336px !important;
  z-index: 3;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 43%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.orange:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: solid 113px transparent;
  border-bottom: solid 113px transparent;
  border-left: solid 109px #4C4245;
}

.green {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  height: 226px !important;
  width: 380px !important;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  float: right;
}

.green:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: solid 113px transparent;
  border-bottom: solid 113px transparent;
  border-left: solid 112px #eaeaea;
}

.green:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: solid 113px transparent;
  border-bottom: solid 113px transparent;
  border-left: solid 112px white;
}

.blue {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ededed;
  height: 226px !important;
  width: 383px !important;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.blue:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 250px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.blue:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: solid 115px transparent;
  border-bottom: solid 115px transparent;
  border-left: solid 111px white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row margin-bottom-30 margin-top-20 ordering" style="margin-top:38px;margin-bottom:38px;">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="orange">
            <span class="spanone">Step 1</span>
            <span class="spananother">Send us your file &</span>
            <span class="spanthird">Project Details,</span>
            <span class="spanfourth">You will recieve a</span>
            <span class="spanfifth">customized estimated link back</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="green">
            <span class="spanone" style="color:#4C4245">Step 2</span>
            <span class="spananother" style="color:#4C4245;width:180px">Click "Make my Sign" on</span>
            <span class="spanthird" style="color:#4C4245">the estimated link,</span>
            <span class="spanfourth" style="color:#4C4245;left:39%">You will recieve a</span>
            <span class="spanfifth" style="color:#4C4245;left:26%;width:251px;">customized completed notification</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="blue">
            <span class="spanone" style="color:#4C4245">Step 3</span>
            <span class="spananother" style="color:#4C4245;width:180px">Click "Ship my Sign" on</span>
            <span class="spanthird" style="color:#4C4245;left:45%">the completion,</span>
            <span class="spanfourth" style="color:#4C4245;left:45%">notification link</span>
            <span class="spanfifth" style="color:#4C4245;left:26%;width:251px;">Your new sign is on its way-!!</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know how to do it using MEDIA Query but I want to keep it responsive using minimum media query.

The image which I have made using CSS

[image]

Comment: its responsive only. how do you want it to be?

Comment: when I check for responsivess on desktop the three boxes get  away from each other.I want them to be joined in every desktop

Comment: what you mean by joined? on the same line adjacent to each other? or one below the other

Comment: Adjacent to each other  as shown in image

Comment: you should be taking a tour on how the `col-` classes work in bootstrap. it would not work as you say. you may have to use media queries instead

Comment: I know how to do it using media query but I was thinking of avoiding media query .. Never Mind. But can you guide me when testing for responsiveness of website  which all screen should I test. Like HD : 1366 * 768 . Any other Screen Size?

Comment: you can have 4 break points, the resolutions is upto u to select. the common resolutions are <320, 720, 1080, and more

Answer (score 0):

use bootstrap class **col-xs** with all the **col-lg** like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
   rest of tag goes here...
</div>
```

Comment: I am using col-lg-12 but issue is that it does not make it appear same on every desktop.

Comment: you need to use all class "col-md-12, col-sm-12, col-xs-12". it will manage

Comment: I would suggest you to first run my code and check for responsiveness on just desktop and then you will get to know my problem clearly

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I try my best. Please check.

```css
.ordering span{
  font-size:16px;
}
.ordering .spanone {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  left: 43%;
  right: 50%;
  font-size: 25px;
  top: 12%;
}

.ordering .spananother {
  position: absolute;
  width: 138px;
  left: 35%;
  right: 50%;  
  top: 35%;
}

.ordering .spanthird {
  position: absolute;
  width: 138px;
  top: 45%;
  left: 39%;
  right: 50%;  
}

.ordering .spanfourth {
  position: absolute;
  width: 138px;
  top: 55%;
  left: 35%;
  right: 50%;  
}

.ordering .spanfifth {
  position: absolute;
  width: 229px;
  top: 66%;
  left: 24%;
  right: 50%;  
}

.orange {
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #4C4245;
  height: 226px !important;
  width: 336px !important;
  z-index: 3;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 43%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.orange:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: solid 113px transparent;
  border-bottom: solid 113px transparent;
  border-left: solid 109px #4C4245;
}

.green {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  height: 226px !important;
  width: 380px !important;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  float: right;
}

.green:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: solid 113px transparent;
  border-bottom: solid 113px transparent;
  border-left: solid 112px #eaeaea;
}

.green:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: solid 113px transparent;
  border-bottom: solid 113px transparent;
  border-left: solid 112px white;
}

.blue {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ededed;
  height: 226px !important;
  width: 383px !important;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.blue:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 250px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.blue:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: solid 115px transparent;
  border-bottom: solid 115px transparent;
  border-left: solid 111px white;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1280px){
.orange::after { 
  border-left: 59px solid #4c4245; 
}
.green {  
  width: 320px !important;  
}
.green::after { 
  border-left: 59px solid #eaeaea;  
}
.green::before {  
  border-left: 61px solid white; 
}
.blue { 
  width: 320px !important;
}
.blue::before { 
  border-left: 61px solid white;  
}
}
@media screen and (max-width:1170px){
.orange{  
   margin-right: 10px;
}
.orange::after { 
  border-left: 40px solid #4c4245; 
}
.green {  
  margin-right: 10px;  
}
.green::after { 
  border-left: 40px solid #eaeaea;  
}
.green::before {  
  border-left: 40px solid white; 
}
.blue { 
  margin-right: 0;
}
.blue::before { 
  border-left: 40px solid white;  
}
.ordering span {
 font-size:14px;
}
.ordering .spanfifth {
  left: 21%;
  margin: auto;  
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;  
  width: 139px!important;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width:999px){
.orange{
  width: 226px !important;
   margin-right: 10px;
}
.orange::after { 
  border-left: 40px solid #4c4245; 
}
.green {  
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 250px !important;  
}
.green::after { 
  border-left: 40px solid #eaeaea;  
}
.green::before {  
  border-left: 40px solid white; 
}
.blue { 
  width: 260px !important;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.blue::before { 
  border-left: 40px solid white;  
}
.ordering span {
 font-size:14px;
}
.ordering .spanfifth {
  left: 21%;
  margin: auto;  
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;  
  width: 139px!important;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
.green {  
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 240px !important;  
}
.blue { 
  width: 250px !important;
  margin-right: 0;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width:480px){
.orange{
  width: 120px !important;
   margin-right: 10px;
}
.orange::after { 
  border-left: 20px solid #4c4245; 
}
.green {  
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 150px !important;  
}
.green::after { 
  border-left: 20px solid #eaeaea;  
}
.green::before {  
  border-left: 20px solid white; 
}
.blue { 
  width: 160px !important;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.blue::before { 
  border-left: 20px solid white;  
}
.ordering span {
 font-size:12px;
}
.ordering .spanone {
  font-size: 21px;
  left: 34%; 
  top: 8%; 
}
.ordering .spananother {
  left: 14%;  
  text-align: center;
  top: 29%;
  width: 108px !important;
}
.ordering .spanthird {
  left: 18%;
  position: absolute;  
  top: 40%;
  width: 100px;
}
.ordering .spanfourth {
  left: 16%;  
  top: 51%;
  width: 98px;
}
.ordering .spanfifth {
  left: 5%; 
  text-align: center;
  top: 140px;
  width: 119px !important;
}
.ordering .green .spanthird {
  left: 21%;
  top: 45%; 
}
.ordering .green .spanfourth {
  left: 23%!important;
  top: 53%; 
}
.ordering .green .spanfifth {
  left: 14% !important;
  top: 140px;
}
.ordering .blue .spanthird {
  left: 21% !important;
  top: 45%; 
}
.ordering .blue .spanfourth {
  left: 21%!important;
  top: 54%; 
}
.ordering .blue .spanfifth {
  left: 21%!important;
  top: 140pz; 
}
}
@media screen and (max-width:320px){
.orange {
  margin-right: 0px;
  width: 96% !important;
  float:none;
}
.ordering .col-xs-4 {
  width: 100%;
}
.order_wrap .ordering span {
  font-size: 14px;
  left: 0 !important;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0 !important;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100% !important;
}
.green {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top:10px;
  width: 96% !important;
  float:none;
}
.blue {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top:10px;
  width: 100% !important;
  float:none;
}
.ordering .green .spanthird {
  left: 0;
  top: 40%;
}
.ordering .green .spanfourth {
  left: 0 !important;
  top: 51%;
}
.ordering .green .spanfifth {
  left: 0 !important;
  top: 140px;
}
.ordering .blue .spanthird {
  left: 0 !important;
  top: 40%;
}
.ordering .blue .spanfourth {
  left: 0 !important;
  top: 51%;
}
.ordering .blue .spanfifth {
  left: 0 !important;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid order_wrap">
<div class="row margin-bottom-30 margin-top-20 ordering" style="margin-top:38px;margin-bottom:38px;">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <div class="orange">
            <span class="spanone">Step 1</span>
            <span class="spananother">Send us your file &</span>
            <span class="spanthird">Project Details,</span>
            <span class="spanfourth">You will recieve a</span>
            <span class="spanfifth">customized estimated link back</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <div class="green">
            <span class="spanone" style="color:#4C4245">Step 2</span>
            <span class="spananother" style="color:#4C4245;width:180px">Click "Make my Sign" on</span>
            <span class="spanthird" style="color:#4C4245">the estimated link,</span>
            <span class="spanfourth" style="color:#4C4245;left:39%">You will recieve a</span>
            <span class="spanfifth" style="color:#4C4245;left:26%;width:251px;">customized completed notification</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <div class="blue">
            <span class="spanone" style="color:#4C4245">Step 3</span>
            <span class="spananother" style="color:#4C4245;width:180px">Click "Ship my Sign" on</span>
            <span class="spanthird" style="color:#4C4245;left:45%">the completion,</span>
            <span class="spanfourth" style="color:#4C4245;left:45%">notification link</span>
            <span class="spanfifth" style="color:#4C4245;left:26%;width:251px;">Your new sign is on its way-!!</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for spending your time to do this much for me. But Sorry to Say that's not a responsive code.By the way I made this design Responsive on my own.

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap provides classes for responsive designs.
You have used "**col-lg-4**" which is only applicable for large screens, for responsive you will need to add classes like "**col-md-4, col-sm-4 or col-xs-4**" depends on your requirement.

So just add different col- classes next to col-lg-4 and your code will work completely fine for responsive.

For reference : [Bootstrap Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

**

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
  "Your code"
</div>
```

**